# format ASCII number to ASCII Character in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform is there a way to format an ASCII value typed as an int into the the corresponding ASCII character as a char?

terraform version: v0.13.7

```
device_name = "${format ("xvd%c", 98)}" #xvdb
```

i tried with %c but is throwing error as below

> Error: Error in function call
>
> on ec2.tf line 82, in resource "aws_volume_attachment" "app":   82:
> device_name = "${format ("xvd%c", 98)}"  #xvdb
>
> Call to function "format" failed: unsupported format verb 'c' in "%c"
> at offset 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform does not have a direct function for interpreting numbers as characters in any particular character encoding. The Terraform language does not expose the details of how strings are encoded in memory.

Your example suggests that your goal is to map from an integer to a letter to use as a device name for an EC2 volume attachment. I think the most straightforward answer to meet that need with Terraform would be to hand-write (or, if you wish, use a one-off script to generate) a lookup table:

```
locals {
  device_names = tolist([
    "xvda",
    "xvdb",
    "xvdc",
    "xvdd",
    # (and so on for however many devices you expect to need to support,
    # presumably up to "z" at the worst)
  ])
}
```

A more "tricky" option -- which I personally wouldn't use because it seems opaque and harder for a future reader to understand -- would be to generate some JSON containing an escape sequence for the character you want and then parse that JSON:

```
jsondecode(format("\"\\u%04x\"", 98))
```

This actually uses Unicode encoding values rather than ASCII encoding values, but the first 128 ASCII values match the first 128 Unicode values and so this should be equivalent as long as you only include values in the range 0-127.

Comment: Very new to Terraform and love the idea of it, but have to say that I wish it had more capabilities to handle dynamic situations.  With that out of the way, I have the same challenge where in certain scenarios I will need many more block devices.  I would like a way to define this in an input *.tf file to say, data_file_count = 12, in which case I would need /dev/sdg through /dev/sdr.  I'm having trouble to understand how I could accomplish this with a lookup table (trying to avoid the jsondecode solution).